# Reference to chapter appears as 'ChapterNumber.SectionNumber'

Tags: formatting

I'm compiling the main frame file that has several chapters takes as an `\input` from different files. In the Introduction file I'm referencing the single chapters but instead of getting as a result just the number of the chapter, I get as a result `chapterNumber.randomSectionNumber`. Any ideas on what it might be causing this problem?

**Main file:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\begin{document}
\title{Something}\\
\normallinespacing
\maketitle

\chapter{Introduction}
\input{Introduction}

\part{Part1}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\input{chapter1}
\label{chap:1}

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\input{chapter2}
\label{chap:2}

\part{Part 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\input{chapter3}
\label{chap:3}

\bibliographystyle{splncs}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Introduction file:

```
in Chapter ~\ref{chap:2}, in Chapter ~\ref{chap:3}.
```

Chapter file

```
text
\section{1}
text
\section{n}
text
```

Comment: Your `\label{chap:1}` etc. is too late! You have to put it directly after `\chapter{Chapter 1}`, otherwise `\label` will use the next counter being fed to `\refstepcounter` in your `\input` files, e.g. a section or equation

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I put it right after the \chapter{} and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ChristianHupfer stated in his comment: you have to use the `\label` command directly after you issued any `\chapter` or `\section`-command.

The `\label`-command will store the last changed counter.  If the last changed counter in your included files was, for example, an equation, than the label would reference that equation counter.

```
\part{Main Part}
\chapter{Chapter 3}\label{chap:3}
```

should give correct references.

Comment: The answering force is strong in you ;-)

Comment: `\LaTeX` you must!